# Table loads previous row which is deleted when sorting

Tags: tablesorter

I am trying to add jquery table sorter. It is working. I have a delete row option in each row with a button, and when I delete a row and try to sort the table again the previously deleted data is loading. How can I solve it. My code is here ,

```
setTimeout(function(){

 if (!self.isFirstInit) {

    $('#fixedTable').tablesorter({  

       headers: {
          0:{sorter: false},
          1:{sorter: false},
          2:{sorter: false}
       }
    });

    self.isFirstInit = true;

    $("#fixedTable").fixheadertable({
       colratio: [32, 32, 32, 130, 130, 110, 110, 86, 86, 93, 93],
       height: 574,
       zebra: true,
       resizeCol: true
    });  
 }

 $('#fixedTable').triggerHandler('update');

}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#fixedTable').trigger('update');` not `.triggerHandler()`.